# Separation of users columns in another table

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I've got a quite a lot of columns on the `users` table and I have been cleaning it up recently. Now since I'm searching over the `users` I figured it would improve performance if I separated verification columns from user. I'm talking about these kind of columns :

```
verified_telephone_number
verified_telephone_by_id
verified_photo_by_id
verified_photo_source
verified_photo
verified_photo_at
video_call_requested
skip_video
```

So I was thinking to create `verifications` table with each user having one verification and verification having these above attributes and some more.

Is there a downside to this approach? I mean for one, in terms of count, there will be `verifications` rows = `users` rows(count). Instead of having these extra columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a 1:1 mapping is sensible when part of the table is heavily accessed and part of it is lightly used.

It's a good choice.